# React TS - disallow manual state change

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

Is there a way to disallow manual state change and allow only using setState?

```
const App = (props) => {
 const [data, setData] = useState({x: 1})

 data.x = 2 // how to forbid this?
 setData({x: 2}) // it's ok
}
```

Or the only way is to use Readonly interface?

```
interface ReadOnlyX {
   readonly x: number
}

const App = (props) => {
   const [data, setData] = useState<ReadOnlyX>({x: 1})
   data.x = 2 // forbidden
   setData({x: 2}) // it's ok
}
```

Comment: Is there a *problem* with using `readonly`? Note that you can use the utility type to apply it more easily: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlyt

Comment: @jonrsharpe yep, if you need to type it for every useState in project. I think i can just make a wrapper for useState using your suggestion about Readonly<T>.